# How to determine the value of  in a linear equation system to ensure that the sum of all columns in a matrix is less than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matlab

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with an assignment. It's related to linear equation systems, and I need to fill in some code and answer a few questions. The part I'm currently stuck on involves determining the value of  in the code snippet below:

```
nList = [3, 30, 300, 3000];
for i=1:length(nList)  
    n = nList(i);
    I = eye(n); 
    R = rand(n);
    k = ?; 
    A = I - k*R;
    C = k*R
```

Specifically, I'm unsure whether the value of  should be set to `1/sum(R(:))` or `1/max(sum(R,1))`. The goal is to ensure that the sum of all columns in the matrix `C` is less than 1.

After some research, I found that `1/sum(R(:))` is correct but too strict, as it would make the sum of the whole matrix equal to 1. On the other hand, `1/max(R(:))` is incorrect because it would make the largest element in  equal to 1, but the sum of columns could still exceed 1.

So I was told a better approach would be to use `1/max(sum(R,1))`. This calculates the sum of each column in , then divides it by the largest sum, and that if you need the sum to be strictly less than 1, we could subtract a very small number or multiply it by a value slightly less than 1.

If you have any insights or suggestions regarding this issue, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: Before thinking of translating to Matlab, why not write it in mathjax?